# configure minio in docker to use https

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minio

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: server -C /etc/minio --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
    volumes:
      - minio:/data
      - /etc/minio:/root/.minio/
      - /etc/minio:/etc/minio/
      
volumes:
  minio:
```

`ls -l /etc/minio/`:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 20 11:43 CAs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59 May 20 11:45 private.key -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   61 May 20 11:44 public.crt -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
```

accessing via http works but https does **not**. I have no clue, what is wrong. Sadly the logs don't show anything and the docs are also not helping.

Comment: May I ask what your final compose file looks like? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symlinks `private.key` and `public.crt` can't be resolved because the targets don't exist inside the container.

The easiest way would be to mount `/etc/letsencrypt` inside the container as well.

Keep in mind that you need to restart the container (or at least reload the minio process inside the container) after every certificate renewal.

Comment: great, that seems to have been the issue. now i gotta figure this out: `Unable to load the TLS configuration: Could not read PEM block from file /etc/minio/certs/public.crt`. any idea :( ?

Comment: That would be a topic for a new question.

Comment: My first guess would be a wrong path in the minio config (`/etc/minio/certs/public.crt` vs `/etc/minio/public.crt`)

Comment: figured it out. it did not like that i linked the `fullchain.pem` and rather expected `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem`

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at the error, I agree it might be because it can't read the certificates, however I believe it's a permission issue, not a wrong path issue..so I would say use chown to change permissions of the directory and the file

Answer (score 0):

**docker_compose.yml**

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge


services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - /data/minio:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: 'nginx'
    hostname: 'nginx'
    ports:
      - "8443:8443" 
      - "8444:8444" 
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=minio.example.com"
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=8443"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - ./conf/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"
      - '/etc/letsencrypt/live/:/etc/letsencrypt/live/'
      - '/etc/letsencrypt/archive/:/etc/letsencrypt/archive/'
volumes:
  minio_storage: {}
```

**app.conf should be placed in conf folder**

```
upstream minio {
  server minio:9001;
  keepalive 15;
}
upstream minio_api {
  server minio:9000;
  keepalive 15;
}
server {
  listen 8443 ssl;
  server_name minio.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/minio.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/minio.example.com/privkey.pem;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://minio;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  }
}
server {
  listen 8444 ssl;
  server_name minio.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/minio.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/minio.example.com/privkey.pem;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://minio_api;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  }

}
```

**Check the permissions for /etc/letsencrypt folder because the containers are running under non privileged user**